# Super high accuracy with high loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am training a 1D CNN on a bunch of images with multi-label classification. I have an accuracy of almost 100% but loss of ~5 at the same time. What's going on?, any help is appreciated.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(137,236)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Training:
[image]

Comment: What are the range of values for your input? Is your data normalized?

Comment: The input is images as arrays. All the values have been divided by 255.

Comment: try removing all your dropouts

Comment: @ksooklall still the same

Comment: then there is nothing to do here, your model has finished learning (loss doesn't drop anymore) and it's as accurate as it can be, try testing it with model.predict